# Upgrade Terraform's Azure SQL Resource from `azurerm_sql_database` to `azurerm_mssql_database`

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

A while ago I created a serverless Azure SQL resource in Terraform using the [`azurerm_sql_database`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/sql_database.html) block.  Then in March, in azurerm version [2.3](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/releases/tag/v2.3.0) they came out with the [`azurerm_mssql_database`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/mssql_database.html) block, which [as I understand](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/6502) is intended to replace `azurerm_sql_database`.

I need to change the `auto_pause_delay_in_minutes` setting, which is only available in `azurerm_mssql_database`.  So I guess I need to upgrade now, before there's any official guidance (that I can find) on how to perform the upgrade.  If I perform these steps:

- Replace `azurerm_sql_database` with `azurerm_mssql_database`
- Remove `resource_group_name`
- Remove `location`
- Replace `requested_service_objective_name` with `sku_name`
- Replace `server_name` with `server_id`

Then terraform tries to delete my database and create a new one, and I get an error like "A resource with the ID [id] already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State."

How do I perform the upgrade and set `auto_pause_delay_in_minutes` without deleting my database?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The old resource in Azure needs to be imported into the new resource definition in terraform. Then the old resource state in terraform needs remove. See the following walk through.  Modify for whatever additional parameters you need, it is the same workflow.

First build the `azurerm_sql_database` resource:

```
# cat .\main.tf
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "~>2.19.0"
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_sql_server" "example" {
  name                         = "pearcecexamplesqlserver"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                     = "East US"
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "4dm1n157r470r"
  administrator_login_password = "4-v3ry-53cr37-p455w0rd"

}

resource "azurerm_sql_database" "example" {
  name                = "pearcecexamplesqldatabase"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = "East US"
  server_name         = azurerm_sql_server.example.name
}
```

**Terraform Apply** -- Assuming a clean creation

Change the resource to `azurerm_mssql_database` and update the parameters

```
cat .\main.tf
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "~>2.19.0"
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_sql_server" "example" {
  name                         = "pearcecexamplesqlserver"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                     = "East US"
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "4dm1n157r470r"
  administrator_login_password = "4-v3ry-53cr37-p455w0rd"

}

resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "example" {
  name                = "pearcecexamplesqldatabase"
  server_id           = azurerm_sql_server.example.id
}
```

**Terraform Apply** -- Uh oh

```
# terraform apply
azurerm_resource_group.example: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/example-resources]
azurerm_sql_database.example: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/example-resources/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/pearcecexamplesqlserver/databases/pearcecexamplesqldatabase]
azurerm_sql_server.example: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/example-resources/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/pearcecexamplesqlserver]

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create
  - destroy

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # azurerm_mssql_database.example will be created
  + resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "example" {
      + auto_pause_delay_in_minutes = (known after apply)
      + collation                   = (known after apply)
      + create_mode                 = (known after apply)
      + creation_source_database_id = (known after apply)
      + id                          = (known after apply)
      + license_type                = (known after apply)
      + max_size_gb                 = (known after apply)
      + min_capacity                = (known after apply)
      + name                        = "pearcecexamplesqldatabase"
      + read_replica_count          = (known after apply)
      + read_scale                  = (known after apply)
      + restore_point_in_time       = (known after apply)
      + sample_name                 = (known after apply)
      + server_id                   = "/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/example-resources/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/pearcecexamplesqlserver"
      + sku_name                    = (known after apply)
      + zone_redundant              = (known after apply)

      + threat_detection_policy {
          + disabled_alerts            = (known after apply)
          + email_account_admins       = (known after apply)
          + email_addresses            = (known after apply)
          + retention_days             = (known after apply)
          + state                      = (known after apply)
          + storage_account_access_key = (sensitive value)
          + storage_endpoint           = (known after apply)
          + use_server_default         = (known after apply)
        }
    }

  # azurerm_sql_database.example will be destroyed
  - resource "azurerm_sql_database" "example" {
      - collation                        = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" -> null
      - create_mode                      = "Default" -> null
      - creation_date                    = "2020-07-31T17:54:48.453Z" -> null
      - default_secondary_location       = "West US" -> null
      - edition                          = "GeneralPurpose" -> null
      - id                               = "/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/example-resources/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/pearcecexamplesqlserver/databases/pearcecexamplesqldatabase" -> null
      - location                         = "eastus" -> null
      - max_size_bytes                   = "34359738368" -> null
      - name                             = "pearcecexamplesqldatabase" -> null
      - read_scale                       = false -> null
      - requested_service_objective_id   = "f21733ad-9b9b-4d4e-a4fa-94a133c41718" -> null
      - requested_service_objective_name = "GP_Gen5_2" -> null
      - resource_group_name              = "example-resources" -> null
      - server_name                      = "pearcecexamplesqlserver" -> null
      - tags                             = {} -> null
      - zone_redundant                   = false -> null

      - threat_detection_policy {
          - disabled_alerts      = [] -> null
          - email_account_admins = "Disabled" -> null
          - email_addresses      = [] -> null
          - retention_days       = 0 -> null
          - state                = "Disabled" -> null
          - use_server_default   = "Disabled" -> null
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value:
Apply cancelled
```

**Terraform Import** -- Import the resource

```
# terraform import azurerm_mssql_database.example /subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/example-resources/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/pearcecexamplesqlserver/databases/pearcecexamplesqldatabase
azurerm_mssql_database.example: Importing from ID "/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/example-resources/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/pearcecexamplesqlserver/databases/pearcecexamplesqldatabase"...
azurerm_mssql_database.example: Import prepared!
  Prepared azurerm_mssql_database for import
azurerm_mssql_database.example: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/example-resources/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/pearcecexamplesqlserver/databases/pearcecexamplesqldatabase]

Import successful!

The resources that were imported are shown above. These resources are now in
your Terraform state and will henceforth be managed by Terraform.
```

**Terraform State Remove** -- Remove the old state

```
terraform state rm azurerm_sql_database.example
Removed azurerm_sql_database.example
Successfully removed 1 resource instance(s)
```

**Terraform Apply** - Clean

```
# terraform apply
azurerm_resource_group.example: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/example-resources]
azurerm_sql_server.example: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/example-resources/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/pearcecexamplesqlserver]
azurerm_mssql_database.example: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/example-resources/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/pearcecexamplesqlserver/databases/pearcecexamplesqldatabase]

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.  For anyone in the future who stumbles across this: also delete `create_mode` or it will try to recreate your database.

Comment: @LeeRichardson I stumbled.  I have the exact same scenario.  Can you explain what you meant by "also delete `create_mode`"?

Comment: Sorry @Arthur sadly my memory rarely lasts to the prior day let alone the prior year.  The best I can do is suggest you test and carefully read the plan prior to applying.  If you find value in the comment along the way please consider providing clarification for future folks.

Comment: @LeeRichardson Did you resolve this?