# terraform plan wants to delete and recreate my sql database

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a Azure SQL Server and database managed by terraform.
I have updated by terraform scripts to add a VM.

When I generate my Plan terraform wants to destroy my database and server and recreate them. I do not want this to happen! The terraform state is stored in a storage account.

I'd like to understand why terraform wants to do this. Is there a mechanism to understand why terraform has made this decision?

Its possible a 3rd party has circumvented process and made changes (such as changing the admin password of the database).

According to the source here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/b0c897055329438be6a3a159f6ffac4e1ce958f2/internal/services/sql/sql_server_resource.go

The only things that force new, is a name change, a version change or a admin login name. Non of which appear to have changed!

Here is a subset of the generated plan. Apologies for the formating

```
  # module.tenant_infrastructure.azurerm_mssql_database.tenant_sqldb will be created
  + resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "tenant_sqldb" {
      + auto_pause_delay_in_minutes = (known after apply)
      + collation                   = (known after apply)
      + create_mode                 = "Default"
      + creation_source_database_id = (known after apply)
      + extended_auditing_policy    = (known after apply)
      + geo_backup_enabled          = true
      + id                          = (known after apply)
      + license_type                = (known after apply)
      + max_size_gb                 = 250
      + min_capacity                = (known after apply)
      + name                        = "sqldb-productname-tenant2"
      + read_replica_count          = (known after apply)
      + read_scale                  = (known after apply)
      + restore_point_in_time       = (known after apply)
      + sample_name                 = (known after apply)
      + server_id                   = (known after apply)
      + sku_name                    = "S1"
      + storage_account_type        = "GRS"
      + tags                        = {
          + "Application" = "productname"
          + "CustomerId"  = "1"
          + "Environment" = "prod"
          + "Tenant"      = "2"
        }
      + zone_redundant              = (known after apply)

      + long_term_retention_policy {
          + monthly_retention = (known after apply)
          + week_of_year      = (known after apply)
          + weekly_retention  = (known after apply)
          + yearly_retention  = (known after apply)
        }

      + short_term_retention_policy {
          + retention_days = (known after apply)
        }

      + threat_detection_policy {
          + disabled_alerts            = (known after apply)
          + email_account_admins       = (known after apply)
          + email_addresses            = (known after apply)
          + retention_days             = (known after apply)
          + state                      = (known after apply)
          + storage_account_access_key = (sensitive value)
          + storage_endpoint           = (known after apply)
          + use_server_default         = (known after apply)
        }

      + timeouts {
          + create = "60m"
          + read   = "60m"
          + update = "60m"
        }
    }

  # module.tenant_infrastructure.azurerm_mssql_server.tenant_sql will be created
  + resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "tenant_sql" {
      + administrator_login               = "companynameAdmin"
      + administrator_login_password      = (sensitive value)
      + connection_policy                 = "Default"
      + extended_auditing_policy          = (known after apply)
      + fully_qualified_domain_name       = (known after apply)
      + id                                = (known after apply)
      + location                          = "uksouth"
      + name                              = "sql-productname-tenant2-prod"
      + primary_user_assigned_identity_id = (known after apply)
      + public_network_access_enabled     = true
      + resource_group_name               = "rg-productname-tenant2-001"
      + restorable_dropped_database_ids   = (known after apply)
      + tags                              = {
          + "Application" = "productname"
          + "CustomerId"  = "1"
          + "Environment" = "prod"
          + "Tenant"      = "2"
        }
      + version                           = "12.0"

      + azuread_administrator {
          + azuread_authentication_only = (known after apply)
          + login_username              = "companyname.productname.TENANT.DB_ADMIN"
          + object_id                   = "1e3f10f4-ade1-44cc-80a7-ea2191e6f5fd"
          + tenant_id                   = "yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy"
        }

      + timeouts {
          + create = "60m"
          + read   = "60m"
          + update = "60m"
        }
    }

  # module.tenant_infrastructure.azurerm_mssql_virtual_network_rule.tenant_sql_subnet_rule_management_access will be created
  + resource "azurerm_mssql_virtual_network_rule" "tenant_sql_subnet_rule_management_access" {
      + id                                   = (known after apply)
      + ignore_missing_vnet_service_endpoint = true
      + name                                 = "allowManagementSubnetAccess"
      + server_id                            = (known after apply)
      + subnet_id                            = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-productname-shared-001/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-productname-shared-001/subnets/snet-productname-shared-management-001"
    }

  # module.tenant_infrastructure.azurerm_mssql_virtual_network_rule.tenant_sql_subnet_rule_tenant_access will be created
  + resource "azurerm_mssql_virtual_network_rule" "tenant_sql_subnet_rule_tenant_access" {
      + id                                   = (known after apply)
      + ignore_missing_vnet_service_endpoint = false
      + name                                 = "allowTenantSubnetAccess"
      + server_id                            = (known after apply)
      + subnet_id                            = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-productname-tenant2-001/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-productname-tenant2-001/subnets/snet-productname-tenant2-001"
    }



  # module.tenant_infrastructure.azurerm_sql_active_directory_administrator.tenant_sql_aad_admin will be destroyed
  - resource "azurerm_sql_active_directory_administrator" "tenant_sql_aad_admin" {
      - azuread_authentication_only = false -> null
      - id                          = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-productname-tenant2-001/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sql-productname-tenant2-prod/administrators/activeDirectory" -> null
      - login                       = "companyname.productname.TENANT.DB_ADMIN" -> null
      - object_id                   = "1e3f10f4-ade1-44cc-80a7-ea2191e6f5fd" -> null
      - resource_group_name         = "rg-productname-tenant2-001" -> null
      - server_name                 = "sql-productname-tenant2-prod" -> null
      - tenant_id                   = "yyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyy" -> null
    }

  # module.tenant_infrastructure.azurerm_sql_database.tenant_sqldb will be destroyed
  - resource "azurerm_sql_database" "tenant_sqldb" {
      - collation                        = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" -> null
      - create_mode                      = "Default" -> null
      - creation_date                    = "2021-12-08T23:08:01.023Z" -> null
      - default_secondary_location       = "UK West" -> null
      - edition                          = "Standard" -> null
      - extended_auditing_policy         = [] -> null
      - id                               = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-productname-tenant2-001/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sql-productname-tenant2-prod/databases/sqldb-productname-tenant2" -> null
      - location                         = "uksouth" -> null
      - max_size_bytes                   = "268435456000" -> null
      - name                             = "sqldb-productname-tenant2" -> null
      - read_scale                       = false -> null
      - requested_service_objective_id   = "1b1ebd4d-d903-4baa-97f9-4ea675f5e928" -> null
      - requested_service_objective_name = "S1" -> null
      - resource_group_name              = "rg-productname-tenant2-001" -> null
      - server_name                      = "sql-productname-tenant2-prod" -> null
      - tags                             = {
          - "Application" = "productname"
          - "CustomerId"  = "1"
          - "Environment" = "prod"
          - "Tenant"      = "2"
        } -> null
      - zone_redundant                   = false -> null

      - threat_detection_policy {
          - disabled_alerts      = [] -> null
          - email_account_admins = "Disabled" -> null
          - email_addresses      = [] -> null
          - retention_days       = 0 -> null
          - state                = "Disabled" -> null
          - use_server_default   = "Disabled" -> null
        }
    }

  # module.tenant_infrastructure.azurerm_sql_server.tenant_sql will be destroyed
  - resource "azurerm_sql_server" "tenant_sql" {
      - administrator_login          = "companynameAdmin" -> null
      - administrator_login_password = (sensitive value)
      - connection_policy            = "Default" -> null
      - extended_auditing_policy     = [] -> null
      - fully_qualified_domain_name  = "sql-productname-tenant2-prod.database.windows.net" -> null
      - id                           = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-productname-tenant2-001/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sql-productname-tenant2-prod" -> null
      - location                     = "uksouth" -> null
      - name                         = "sql-productname-tenant2-prod" -> null
      - resource_group_name          = "rg-productname-tenant2-001" -> null
      - tags                         = {
          - "Application" = "productname"
          - "CustomerId"  = "1"
          - "Environment" = "prod"
          - "Tenant"      = "2"
        } -> null
      - version                      = "12.0" -> null

      - threat_detection_policy {
          - disabled_alerts      = [
              - "",
            ] -> null
          - email_account_admins = false -> null
          - email_addresses      = [
              - "",
            ] -> null
          - retention_days       = 0 -> null
          - state                = "Disabled" -> null
        }
    }

  # module.tenant_infrastructure.azurerm_sql_virtual_network_rule.tenant_sql_subnet_rule_management_access will be destroyed
  - resource "azurerm_sql_virtual_network_rule" "tenant_sql_subnet_rule_management_access" {
      - id                                   = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-productname-tenant2-001/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sql-productname-tenant2-prod/virtualNetworkRules/allowManagementSubnetAccess" -> null
      - ignore_missing_vnet_service_endpoint = true -> null
      - name                                 = "allowManagementSubnetAccess" -> null
      - resource_group_name                  = "rg-productname-tenant2-001" -> null
      - server_name                          = "sql-productname-tenant2-prod" -> null
      - subnet_id                            = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-productname-shared-001/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-productname-shared-001/subnets/snet-productname-shared-management-001" -> null
    }
```

The module code is below.

Note that I subsequently added a lifecycle block to the SQL Database which didn't seem to prevent the plan from trying to delete the resources!

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "tenant_sql" {
  name                         = "sql-product-tenant${var.tenant}-${var.environment}"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.tenant_rg.name
  location                     = var.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = var.sql_server_admin_login
  administrator_login_password = random_password.sql_server_admin_password.result

   tags = {
        Application = "product"
      Tenant = var.tenant
      CustomerId = var.customer_id
      Environment = var.environment
    }

     timeouts {
    create = "60m"
    update = "60m"
    read ="60m"
  }

    azuread_administrator {
    login_username = "COMPANY.PRODUCT.TENANT.DB_ADMIN"
    object_id      = local.groups.COMPANY.PRODUCT.TENANT.DB_ADMIN
    tenant_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
    ignore_changes = ["administrator_login", "administrator_login_password"]
  }
}


resource "azurerm_mssql_virtual_network_rule" "tenant_sql_subnet_rule_tenant_access" {
  name                = "allowTenantSubnetAccess"
  server_id         = azurerm_mssql_server.tenant_sql.id
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.tenant_subnet.id
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_virtual_network_rule" "tenant_sql_subnet_rule_management_access" {
  name                = "allowManagementSubnetAccess"
  server_id         = azurerm_mssql_server.tenant_sql.id
  subnet_id           = data.azurerm_subnet.shared_management_subnet.id
  ignore_missing_vnet_service_endpoint = true
}


resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "tenant_sqldb" {
  name                = "sqldb-product-tenant${var.tenant}"
  server_id         = azurerm_mssql_server.tenant_sql.id
  sku_name          = var.database_is_premium == true ? "P4" : "S1"
  create_mode                      = "Default"


max_size_gb     = 250 

   tags = {
        Application = "product"
      Tenant = var.tenant
      CustomerId = var.customer_id
      Environment = var.environment
    }

  timeouts {
    create = "60m"
    update = "60m"
    read ="60m"
  }
}
```

Comment: If you didn't change your terraform code, maybe you (or someone) updated the mysql db outside of terraform and that's why it tries to recreate it to match the desired configuration.

Comment: Feel free providing us with code and logs for more precise help

Comment: Indeed, as I mentioned I think this is the root cause. What I'd like to do is understand which properties are triggering the recreation. Do you know if there is a mechanism to determine this? I'll fall back to reading the source code if need be

Comment: When I run a `terraform apply` it prompts me what configuration changed outside of terraform. Doesn't it do the same on the `terraform plan`?

Comment: It states its refreshing the state and then lists all the items that it will create/delete and update

Comment: Look at my answer to see how it should appears on your log

Comment: @iasksillyquestions can you add the module code? Or at least can you check if the name or something else in the DB resource depends on a data source or something that has changed in between? Was e.g. a variable value changed or updated to use defaults?

Comment: @MarkoE The name hasnt changed (although it does rely on variables)

Comment: @MarkoE I added the module code above.

Comment: Did you re-run `terraform init` after you updated the module code if the module code is stored in a VCS?

Comment: Also, have you by any chance updated the Azure provider version in the meantime?

Comment: Its highly likely Ive updated the provider version yes.

Comment: I'm using Azure devops pipelines. This always will run an init before creating the plan

Comment: Ok, because if the provider was updated there is a line I see in the new resource but I didn't see in any of the module or the DB that will get deleted: `storage_account_type = "GRS"`.

Comment: @MarkoE That makes sense for the database - but the server?

Comment: Dunno, maybe because of the implicit dependency? Have any of the local variables (e.g., `local.groups.COMPANY.PRODUCT.TENANT.DB_ADMIN`) or `azurerm_client_config` data source changed? Anyway, it's probably Azure provider specific and I don't know much about that.

Comment: Looking at the code, storage_account_type  doesnt appear to ForceNew? Was this a hunch?

Answer (score 1):

By inspecting the provided plan output with formatting in the third iteration of the question, I can see why the re-creation is being forced. The provider does not display any information about a value change forcing a re-creation, nor does it seem to display any real value changes at all. My next theory was that a resource was renamed in the config, and sure enough:

```
module.tenant_infrastructure.azurerm_sql_database.tenant_sqldb --> module.tenant_infrastructure.azurerm_mssql_database.tenant_sqldb
```

It may be frustrating to hear this, but debugging something like this really comes down to experience, and having observed it before.

You can fix this by modifying the state with simple [`terraform state`](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/state/mv) commands within the Terraform CLI:

```
terraform state mv module.tenant_infrastructure.azurerm_sql_database.tenant_sqldb module.tenant_infrastructure.azurerm_mssql_database.tenant_sqldb
terraform state mv module.tenant_infrastructure.azurerm_sql_server.tenant_sql module.tenant_infrastructure.azurerm_mssql_server.tenant_sql
terraform state mv module.tenant_infrastructure.azurerm_sql_virtual_network_rule.tenant_sql_subnet_rule_management_access module.tenant_infrastructure.azurerm_mssql_virtual_network_rule.tenant_sql_subnet_rule_management_access
```

The `module.tenant_infrastructure.azurerm_sql_database.tenant_sqldb` seems to be replaced by the `module.tenant_infrastructure.azurerm_mssql_virtual_network_rule.tenant_sql_subnet_rule_tenant_access`. These are difference resources, and therefore this single destruction and creation seems to be intentional.

You mention in the comments that you are using ADO to execute TF, in which case you may need to modify the pipeline temporarily to update the state with these commands.

Additionally, if you are using Terraform 1.1 or later, then you can also request the module author to add [the moved block](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/refactoring#moved-block-syntax) to the resources to avoid this state issue with the renaming.

Comment: Great catch. I found this which seems to be the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63194330/upgrade-terraforms-azure-sql-resource-from-azurerm-sql-database-to-azurerm-m

Comment: @iasksillyquestions Oh right this is an Azure API change and not a resource rename. Then yes: you would need to `terraform state rm` and then `terraform import`.

Comment: FWIW, newer versions of Terraform (I think v1.1 and later) should include an extra note after the `# ADDRESS will be destroyed` message, like `# (because ADDRESS is not in configuration)`, to give a little more insight into why Terraform is proposing to destroy a particular object. Older versions are less forthcoming about why a particular action was planned though, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I got my configuration matching what's provisionned :

[image]

Now I do some update on azure portal, here adding a configuration value on an azure function :
[image]

I run `terraform apply` without touching the code :

[image]

That change is detected and so terraform will "fix" it to match the provided configuration (understand, removing that new configuration done manually).

If you wan't to keep that change, you must [import](https://www.terraform.io/cli/import) it in your code.

Comment: On the items its updating the plan will show the changes (as yours does above). It does not do this for items its deleting and recreating  for me.

Comment: Yup, the question asks about recreating not updating in place.

Comment: @MarkoE who is this comment aimed at? The question states that I dont want the SQL server to be deleted. In fact I dont want it changed at all, but an update in place would be better than a deletion!

Comment: I wanted to say that the answer shows a solution to a different problem than the one stated in the original question.