# Migrating azure_sql_database to azure_mssql_database

Tags: azure, terraform

We have a live database in Azure(Production application) managing through terraform script.

```
 resource "azurerm_sql_server" "application_sql_server" { 
   name = "name-${var.resource_suffix}" 
   resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name 
   location = var.location 
   version = "12.0" 
   administrator_login = "<Username>" 
   administrator_login_password = "<password>" 
   identity { 
     type = "SystemAssigned" 
   }  
}
```

Till now using resource of type azurerm_sql_database for managing database. Recently encountered that HashiCorp introduced a new resource to replace azurerm_sql_database. New resource is azurerm_mssql_database. New database will be created if we simple replace azurerm_sql_database resouce with azurerm_mssql_database in terraform script. What is the right way to change the resource type without effecting the existing database.

Comment: If possible, can you share the code you have in your environment. And one of the best approaches is to have a terraform back up in a state file which `terraform.tfstatebackup`. @Karkala Srikanth

Comment: @Jahnavi Here is the current sql resource, Just we are changing it to mssql_datasource resource "azurerm_sql_server" "application_sql_server" {
  name                         = "name-${var.resource_suffix}"
  resource_group_name          = var.resource_group_name
  location                     = var.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "<Username>"
  administrator_login_password = "<password>"

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

Comment: @Jahnavi We are planing to perform below steps, backup state file, import existing resource to mssql_database resource using terraform import --> Remove sql_database from state file --> apply terraform with mssql_database resource

Answer (score 0):

When you create a resource with Terraform, a terraform state backup file is loaded into the backend that contains the deployed resource definitions.

After creating the `"azurerm_sql_databse"` resource, first import it into the current resource definition using the `terraform state backup` file.

This means that the old Azure resource needs to be imported into the new resource definition in terraform. Remove the old resource configuration from the terraform state file and save the file after import.

*Previously I have created an old database resource with terraform as shown.*

[image]

[image]

Now I wanted it to migrate from `azurerm_sql_databse` to `azurerm_mssql_databse`.

Get the previously created resource definition by importing it into current terraform resource file for migrating it to the latest resource [`azurerm_mssql_databse`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/mssql_database) release.

```bash
 terraform import azurerm_mssql_database.example "resourceID"
```

[image]

Now it is migrated into `azurerm_mssql_database` resource.

Remove the old resource from the state file using below command.

```bash
terraform state rm azurerm_sql_database.example
```

Now run terraform apply for complete migration to achieve your requirement.

Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63194330/upgrade-terraforms-azure-sql-resource-from-azurerm-sql-database-to-azurerm-m) by @Christian Pearce for the relevant migration.

Comment: is this the only solution for migration. Because I have to perform these steps for server, database, azurerm_sql_virtual_network_rule  and azurerm_sql_firewall_rule. other option, just migrate server and Database, let remaining resources be created as new. do you think that works?

Comment: Yes it works for all. @KarkalaSrikanth